# How to send HTML form data as JSON to endpoint http://localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a simple HTML form and a Java Script function that makes a JSON with the data. All I need now is to send it to endpoint "http://localhost:8080" and check that the JSON got there. So far I got this:

```js
function create_send_Json(){
    
    // get name
    var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["first_name"].value;
    var lname = document.forms["myForm"]["last_name"].value;
    
    // make JSON
    data = { "fname": fname, "lname": lname};
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    // Send data
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080';

    xhr.open("POST", url); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    xhr.send(jsonData);

    return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "action.js" ></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return create_send_Json();" name="myForm">
        <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname"></p>

        <p><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname"></p>

        <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="submitform()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I think this is not working.

Thanks in advance.

------ EDIT ---------

To be clear, I used the following to check if it works:

```
alert('status: '+xhr.status + ' ,readyState: '+xhr.readyState);
```

and received

```
status: 0 ,readyState: 1
```

Also, I made the suggested changes in the code but still need to check if the json was received on the other side.

Comment: You don't require form onSubmit method if you're having a submit button within the form, check my answer regarding the same. all you need to do is add your submit method to your button as below

Comment: Also, to submit a form use either **onsubmit** on the HTML FORM TAG or the **onclick** event on the BUTTON TAG not both

Comment: @Jon.Frenchtoast What is fine in your sight ?

Comment: @Jon.Frenchtoast I checked the xhr.status and xhr.readyState, wich is giving me 0 and 1, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Add the submit event in your submit button instead of your form. change it and you'll good to go.

```
function create_send_Json(){

    // get name
    var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["first_name"].value;
    var lname = document.forms["myForm"]["last_name"].value;

    // make JSON
    data = { "fname": fname, "lname": lname};
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    // Send data
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080';

    xhr.open("POST", url); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    xhr.send(jsonData);

    return false;
}
```

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Form</title>
            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "action.js" ></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm" action="POST">
            <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname"></p>

            <p><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname"></p>

            <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="create_send_Json()">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I check that the json was really sent? Is there a way to monitor that port?

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

Replace submitform with create_send_Json in HTML sumbit button.